# JavaFX java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1, java.util.ConcurrentModificationException решение?

Tags: java, javafx

Всем привет,

разрабатываю маленькую программу клиент для визуализации и записывания показании датчиков температуры и влажности с arduino + DHT22. Сделал GUI - с использованием JavaFX. Но столкнулся с проблемой, время от времени при записи показании более одного часа могут возникнуть JavaFX исключения, в Java я новичек, погуглил что может быть ошибка в использовании одного и того же объекта из разных потоков НО у меня один поток на запись и отрисовку.
Записываю данные в XLS (Excel) с помощью Apache POI.
Прикладываю весь листинг программы, а так же лог исключении. Кто может подсказать в какую сторону копать? На каком этапе вылезают исключения не могу найти так как программа работает несколько часов и в любой момент вылетает Exception.

Сам проект на гите + сорсы:
https://github.com/mozomig/Java-GUI-Serial-port-Arduino

Exception LOG:

```html
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:386)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:355)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.PathUtils.configShape(PathUtils.java:45)
at javafx.scene.shape.Path.impl_configShape(Path.java:251)
at javafx.scene.shape.Path.impl_configShape(Path.java:89)
at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.impl_computeGeomBounds(Shape.java:864)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3593)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3623)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3484)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_intersectsBounds(Node.java:5013)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_pickNodeLocal(Region.java:2931)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_pickNode(Node.java:4912)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3899)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1600(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:1942)
at javafx.scene.Scene.access$6700(Scene.java:159)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3711)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler$1.run(Scene.java:3521)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_intersectsBounds(Node.java:5013)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_pickNodeLocal(Region.java:2931)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_pickNode(Node.java:4912)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3899)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1600(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:1942)
at javafx.scene.Scene.access$6700(Scene.java:159)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3711)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler$1.run(Scene.java:3521)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Согласно ошибке вы где-то в цикле пробегаетесь по коллекции и в этом же цикле пытаетесь коллекцию менять. Так нельзя. Вам надо или в отдельную коллекцию заносить изменения или через интерфейс Iterable работать

Comment: Вы уверены что `serialPortEvent` приходит в ожидаемом вами потоке, т.е. **JavaFX Application Thread**. Проверьте с помощью `Thread.currentThread().getName()`